# ¿Cómo extraer e imprimir contenido de listas en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en python, en un punto determinado del mismo el usuario debe ingresar sus calificaciones y sus créditos, dichos datos son almacenados en una lista correspondiente para cada uno. Lo que quiero conseguir es extraer dichos datos e imprimirlos uno debajo del otro. ej:

98

79

56

He intentado hacerlo, sin embargo solo soy capaz de imprimir el ultimo dato de cada lista. Agradezco de antemano y me disculpo por la ignorancia, estoy en proceso de aprendizaje.

Adjunto un resumen del código que estoy usando.

```
calificacion = 0
limite_opciones_1 = input(str("Número de materias en este período: "))
lista_calificaciones = []
i = 1

def Obtener_calificaciones (calificacion, i, lista_calificaciones, limite_opciones):
    while calificacion >= 0 and calificacion <= 100 and i <= int(limite_opciones):
        calificacion = float(input("-Calificación "+ str(i)+ ": "))
        if calificacion > 0:
            lista_calificaciones.append (calificacion)
        i = i +1

Obtener_calificaciones(calificacion, i,lista_calificaciones, limite_opciones_1)

credito_1 = 0
lista_creditos_1 = []
s_1 = 1

def introduccion_creditos():
    print ("\nIngrese los créditos correspondientes en el mismo orden.\n")

introduccion_creditos()

def obtener_creditos (credito, s,  lista_creditos, limite_opciones):
    while credito >= 0 and credito <= 20 and s <= int(limite_opciones):
        credito = float(input("-Créditos "+ str(s)+ ": "))
        if credito > 0:
            lista_creditos.append (credito)
        s = s +1

obtener_creditos (credito_1, s_1, lista_creditos_1, limite_opciones_1)

for j in range(len(lista_calificaciones)):
    calificaciones_1 = lista_calificaciones[j]

for c in range(len(lista_creditos_1)):
    creditos_1 = lista_creditos_1[c]

print (calificaciones_1)
print (creditos_1)
```

Comment: Hola Alexander, ahora mismo imprimes el último de cada lista porque estas imprimiendo fuera de los for por lo que imprimes los valores finales de ambas listas que asignas en cada uno de ellos. No termino de entender como quieres imprimir, ¿calificación y al lado el cŕedito correspondiente?, ¿calificación y debajo el crédito correspondiente a esa calificacion y luego calificación de nuevo y su crédito....?, ¿ imprimir todas las calificaciones y luego todos los créditos?, etc.

Comment: Calificación y al lado el crédito correspondiente, en caso de que esto sea muy difícil de lograr entonces imprimir primero las calificaciones y luego los créditos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como te he comentado, con tu código recorres ambas listas usando un `for` para cada una de ellas, pero imprimes fuera de los ciclos por lo que, al final, siempre vas a imprimir los últimos elementos de ambas.

Básicamente lo que necesitas es recorrer dos listas con el mismo número de elementos a la vez, para ello debes **usar un solo `for`** para recorrer ambas e imprimir las parejas de datos.

Vamos a crear un pequeño ejemplo primero:

```
lista_calificaciones  = [54.14, 14.454, 98.478, 35.156, 45.0]
lista_creditos_1      = [14.0, 12.5, 8.5, 10.0, 19.0]
```

Hay varias formas, puedes usar los índices como haces tu:

```
for i in range(len(lista_calificaciones)):
    print(lista_calificaciones[i], lista_creditos_1[i])
```

Otra forma más "pythónica" es usar la función [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for cal, cred in zip(lista_calificaciones, lista_creditos_1):
    print(cal, cred)
```

La salida de ambos casos es:

```
54.14 14.0
14.454 12.5
98.478 8.5
35.156 10.0
45.0 19.0
```

Esto solo imprime ambos floats uno al lado del otro separados por un espacio. Para que quede más bonito usa el método `str.format` (mejor que concatenar `str`). Por ejemplo:

```
for cal, cred in zip(lista_calificaciones, lista_creditos_1):
    print('Calificación: {0:.2f}, Créditos: {0:.2f}'.format(cal, cred))
```

**Salida:**

```
Calificación: 54.14, Créditos: 54.14
Calificación: 14.45, Créditos: 14.45
Calificación: 98.48, Créditos: 98.48
Calificación: 35.16, Créditos: 35.16
Calificación: 45.00, Créditos: 45.00
```

En este caso los floats son redondeados a dos decimales (`.2f`). Esto te permite mucha flexibilidad, permitiendo por ejemplo tabular los datos. Un ejemplo simple:

```
sep = '|{}|{}|'.format('-'*16,  '-'*10)
print('{0}\n| Calificaciones | Creditos |\n{0}'.format(sep))
for cal, cred in zip(lista_calificaciones, lista_creditos_1):
    print('| {:>14.2f} | {:>8.2f} |\n{}'.format(cal, cred,  sep))
```

**Salida:**

```
|----------------|----------|
| Calificaciones | Creditos |
|----------------|----------|
|          54.14 |    14.00 |
|----------------|----------|
|          14.45 |    12.50 |
|----------------|----------|
|          98.48 |     8.50 |
|----------------|----------|
|          35.16 |    10.00 |
|----------------|----------|
|          45.00 |    19.00 |
|----------------|----------|
```

Puedes mirarte la documentación oficial para más información:

- [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
- [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Answer (score 0):

Para Imprimir por consola, suelo preferir `dataframes` es la manía antigua de pensar en modo 'Hoja de calculo'.

```
import pandas as pd
lista_calificaciones  = [54.14, 14.454, 98.478, 35.156, 45.0]
lista_creditos_1      = [14.0, 12.5, 8.5, 10.0, 19.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(lista_calificaciones, lista_creditos_1),  columns=['lista_calificaciones','lista_creditos_1'])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para extraer/filtrar es también muy sencillo:

```
# extraer columna
df['lista_calificaciones']

# acceder fila a fila
[(row[1],row[2]) for row in df.itertuples()]

Out[1]:
[(54.140000000000001, 14.0),
 (14.454000000000001, 12.5),
 (98.477999999999994, 8.5),
 (35.155999999999999, 10.0),
 (45.0, 19.0)]

# iterar con filtro, por ejemplo si solo quieres ver aquellas 
#calificaciones y creditos superiores a un 50 (aprobados)

[(row[1],row[2]) for row in df[df['lista_calificaciones']>50].itertuples()]
```